# Getting "pages" from different collection with Assemble

Tags: handlebars.js, gruntjs, template-engine, assemble

Let's say I have a page from a collection where I want to list every yaml tag from a different pages collection. 
If they were in the same collection this would do the trick:

```
<section class="see-also">
<header>Related Contents:</header>
   {{#each tags}}
   <p>In <span class="tag">{{tag}}</span>:</p>
      {{#each pages}}
        <li><a href="{{relative ../../../page.dest dest}}">{{data.title}}</a></li>
      {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
 </section>
```

But since im trying to access this collection from a page on a different one, how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a [custom helper](http://assemble.io/docs/Custom-Helpers.html) for this. Since there is no easy way to write a helper that will work the way you're describing for your specific setup, here is a great example of how a custom helper was used to solve a similar problem: https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/254

Answer (score 0):

If I had this use case I would probably put the 'pages' yaml in a separate yml file instead of embedded on the page.

If in your gruntfile you include a path to data files:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    data: ['<%= site.data %>', 'data/*.yml']
  }
}
```

And your file structure includes:

```
── data
│   └── page1.yml
│   └── page2.yml
```

You can access `{{#each page1.pages}}` from anywhere.

Or you could have a `shared.yml` file that includes information like the pages collection referred to, and the rest of the data stays on each page.

Further resources:

- http://assemble.io/docs/Data.html
- http://assemble.io/docs/YAML-front-matter.html